# Setting specific patch identifier

Tags: netlogo, patch, identifier

I want to have specific 'who' (labels) of the patches.I have attached a picture for it. How can I set it? Is it setting manual 'who' of patch numbers? or Is there any other way of doing it?

Thanks

[picture for patch identifiers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dICIu.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the specific "spiral" sequence in your example, you can use a variant of Luck's solution that takes advantage of NetLogo's default patch sort order:

```
patches-own [ id ]

to setup
  clear-all
  (foreach (sort patches) (range count patches) [ [p n] ->
    ask p [ set id n ]
  ])
  ask patches [ set plabel id ]
end
```

Or you could use a slightly different sort order specified with [`sort-by`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sort-by).

That being said, I don't know what your requirements are, but I would question the idea of having a specific id for patches. Most things in NetLogo can be done without ever refering to an agent's id. The `who` number itself is a relic of very old NetLogo versions and should almost never be used in modern code.

If you want to refer to a specific patch, refer to it by its coordinates, for example: `patch -2 4`.

If you want to store a patch for future reference, store a reference to *the patch itself*, not some kind of id. For example: `ask turtles [ set my-patch one-of patches ]`.

Comment: Thanks for answer and question. These are identifiers for apartments. 00 is a university patch and rest are apartments near university. In every round student will move to nearest apartments for accommodation and if they are filled then to the outer ring of apartments farther from university. These numbers will help to move students to  random specific location. Will these identifier work as I am setting them? Moreover, I don't understand P, n and range. what to write in them to get these unique identifier. Thanks

Comment: I agree with Nicolas- it is probably better to do what you need to without giving the patches specific identification, especially if the students are moving randomly to buildings in the outer ring. If you want visible ID labels for the buildings as specified, my answer above will work, but it will end up being more difficult in the long run to use those ids in procedures.

Answer (score 1):

A patch doesn't have a `who` since that is a turtle-only variable; patches have coordinates instead. However, you could give patches their own id number and use that. If all you need is a 5 x 5 world (as in your picture), you could accomplish what you want in Netlogo code. For example, see the code below (and note that I changed the world settings [to those seen here](https://imgur.com/a/8Y2MK)). However, if you want a world with more patches, I would recommend reading your desired patch values from a file.

```
globals [
  idlist
  ordered_patches
]

patches-own [
  id
]


to setup
  set idlist [ 9 10 11 12 13 24 1 2 3 14 23 8 0 4 15 22 7 6 5 16 21 20 19 18 17 ]
  set ordered_patches sort patches
end


to assign-ids

  ( foreach ordered_patches idlist [
    [ o_patch _id ] -> 
      ask o_patch [ 
        set id _id
      ]
  ]
  )

  ask patches [
    set plabel id
  ]

end
```

Comment: Thank you  Luck for  detailed answer. I am new to netlogo. I hope you won't mind me asking that  in [ o_patch _id ] above list is needed to write again AND   ask o_patch Is it ask ordered-patches?. And what is the purpose of _id. DO I need to put list again here? and what do we meant by this symbol -> . I copied and tried same in Netlogo but many errors appear. please guide.

Comment: Hi Sadaf, I should have specified that I am using Netlogo 6.0; the syntax for the `foreach` primitive is slightly different between versions 5 and 6, which may be the cause of your errors if you are using an older version than I am. Or they could occur if did not use the same world settings as I did as above). I recommend reading the [Netlogo dictionary entry](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/foreach.html) on `foreach` in order to understand what the `->` is doing in the code above- it will also help clarify that "o_patch" and "_id" are just temporary variables for `foreach`.

Comment: ok thanks for clarification. I am now using NetLogo 6. I run the same program but got this error poping up as                                                    All the list arguments to FOREACH must be the same length.
error while observer running FOREACH
  called by procedure ASSIGN-IDS
  called by Button 'assign-ids'

Comment: I have tried this world setting. it works this way. I don't know the difference.[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5dGyd2Qnw40V3Z2ZWkzV2N4c0E/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The "must be the same length" error that you were getting is due to the fact that any lists used in `foreach` must be the same length. So in this example, we asked an ordered list of patches (25 of them) to set their ids to the "idlist", which is a list of 25 items as well. So with this code, you must make sure that you have the same number of ids in your idlist as you do patches in the world. Since your world setting (xmin = -2, xmax = 2, ymin = -2, ymax = 2) gives a world of 25 patches, the code works.